# windows.forms Database-driven application framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm looking for a free or open source windows.forms based framework which facilities database-driven and CRUD apps. 
I appreciate your input.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you except from such a framework? I think DataSets&System.Windows.Forms is what you are looking for.

Comment: not really. I need a complete framework built on top of windows forms